# Django: customer user model superuser

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've created an app with customer user model which inherits from `AbstractBaseUser` and created a `UserManager`. Everything works just fine, except when I try to create a second super user, it replaces the first one. Also, when I log into admin page, it doesn't allow me to edit the user with superuser status. I'm not sure what's causing it, but here are the codes that I'm using...

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.CharField(_('customer id'), primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    phoneNumber = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    #restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    orderStatus = models.BooleanField('Order Placed', default=False)
    numOffense = models.PositiveIntegerField('# Offense', default=0)
    company = models.CharField(_('company'), null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    handle = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=30)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name','phoneNumber']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        '''
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the short name for the user.
        '''
        return self.first_name
```

**managers.py**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Please let me know if you can find any, what needs to be changed. Thank you!

Comment: You do not have `is_superuser` field in your User model

Comment: It creates the field on its own since I'm inheriting `AbstractBaseUser` and in `UserManager` takes care of `is_superuser` field